# Is there any general consideration on the lack of balance in sample size for (any) inference?

Tags: inference, modeling, sample-size, statistical-power, causality

I'm wondering if there are any suggestions, good practices, thoughts about the imbalance between data size in each compared group? I ask apart from any concrete statistical test (Welch, Kruska-Wallis, F in ANOVA, etc.). It's rather about the "philosophical" issue. If we compare, say, 100 and 20, the first one provides more information, the second - fewer. In case of, say, 1000 and 50 it's much fewer. I know, that technically analysis (both frequentist and Bayesian) can be performed on any data, but what about the sense of such comparison?

I read somewhere, that 2:1 imbalance "usually" doesn't pose a problem. But what about 10:1? 50:1?

Are you aware of any such discussion, book, article?

It doesn't have to be about the concrete statistical test and its power (they all have their performance, that's understandable).

Comment: I'm curious how you came to think there would be any philosophical issue with this separate from the statistical performance of tests and estimators. Sample size imbalance is asked about quite frequently on this is site but it was given virtually no attention in my training so I wonder how it has become an issue that warrants concern for some people. If there are philosophical issues I would be very surprised, as I can't even imagine what they could be.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have $n_1 = 100$ observations
from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 50. \sigma = 7)$
and $n_1 = 30$ observations
from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 55. \sigma = 8).$
then you might find a significant difference
between the two population means at the 5% level,
using a Welch 2-sample t test (on account of
different group variances).

For the specific
fictitious samples shown below, the P-value
$0.0002 < 0.05 = 5\%$ detects a highly significant
difference. It is true that the first sample provides more information than the second, but
the result is clear.

```
set.seed(121)
x1 = rnorm(100, 50, 7)
x2 = rnorm( 30, 55, 8)
t.test(x1, x2)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -4.0747, df = 44.036, p-value = 0.0001894
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -8.582399 -2.902207
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 49.32417  55.06647
```

Boxplots also show a difference in location (roughly illustrated by non-overlapping 'notches' in the sides of boxes).

```
boxplot(x1,x2, horizontal=T, notch=T, 
        varwidth=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

If one of the two samples is 'hugely bigger' than
the other, the Welch test still finds a difference
in means. The P-value is not much different than
above, because the relative lack of information
from the smaller sample persists.

```
set.seed(121)
y1 = rnorm(3000, 50, 7)
y2 = rnorm(  30, 55, 8)
t.test(y1, y2)$p.val  # only P-value shown
[1] 0.00282827
```

However, now the sample mean of the larger sample is very nearly the same as the population mean of its 'parent' distribution.

Thus, the P-value of the *two*-sample t test above is not much different from just
using a *one*-sample t test whether sample `y2`
is consistent with $\mu \approx 50.06.$
Both P-values are about $0.003.$

```
mean(y1)
[1] 50.06129

t.test(y2,mu = 50.06)$p.val
[1] 0.002763666
```

If the sample sizes are grossly different, then the main
variability comes from the smaller sample, and
a two-sample test is very nearly the same as an
appropriate one sample test.